# C++ Linux Interrupt nanosleep

Tags: c++, linux

I am using nanosleep to stop a process for a certain time. 
How can I interrupt the nanosleep before the requested time?
Thanks!

Comment: Why do you ask? And why do you use `nanosleep` instead of e.g. `poll` in that case? Explain much more your code....

Answer (score 6):

As mentioned by @Kerrek SB, set-up a signal handler to handle `SIGUSR1`, send the signal to the process using [`kill(1)`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/kill) (or self using [`kill(2)`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/kill)) and check `errno` for `EINTR` upon the return of [`nanosleep(2)`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/nanosleep.2.html) to see if you've been interrupted (in case you want to do something different in that case).

Incidentally, in any use of [`sleep(3)`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/sleep) et al, where you want to guarantee you sleep for (roughly) the required time, you should be taking the start time, checking for `EINTR` and re-sleeping with the revised time if you were interrupted.

A (much) more elegant solution, IMHO, is to set-up an *event* using [`pipe(2)`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/pipe) and use [`poll(2)`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/poll) to listen on the read side of the pipe using with the required sleep timeout.  If you want to interrupt the sleep you simply send a character to the write side of the pipe.  This solution provides a much more fine-grained solution and doesn't require global signal handlers and horrible side-effects.  It's also susceptible to interruption and requires the same `EINTR` restart logic as mentioned above.

**UPDATE**: As mentioned by @John Bartholomew (many thanks), using [`eventfd(2)`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/eventfd) is a better alternative to using [`pipe(2)`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/pipe).  This applies only if you are providing a Linux solution, as it's not supported on BSD (including Mac OS X) :(

This message has been brought to you with the extensive help of [http://linux.die.net](http://linux.die.net/)

Comment: On Linux (since kernel 2.6.22 + glibc 2.8), there is also [eventfd](http://linux.die.net/man/2/eventfd2), which can be used instead of a pipe, with the advantage that "The kernel overhead of an eventfd file descriptor is much lower than that of a pipe, and only one file descriptor is required."

Comment: @JohnBartholomew Hmm, interesting - I use this `pipe/poll` hack on Linux and Mac OSX (to kinda emulate Win32's excellent event APIs), and have been looking for a decent replacement.  Tried `kevent` but that didn't work well, so if that's supported under OSX, it might be what I'm looking for...

Comment: I don't think there can e a cross-platform solution for Linux and OSX at the moment. You need dedicated code for each platform.

Comment: Is it better than using TimerFD_Create + TimerFD_Set with read (and than iterrupting the read by writing to the fd)?

Comment: @user1997268 Sorry I don't know what those function are.